# Bootstrap Date Paginator change language

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I would like to change the language of the bootstrap date paginator: http://jondmiles.com/bootstrap-datepaginator/

Right now my paginator looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7gwW.png

I would like to change the language of the weekdays and the months. I do not know if this is possible, because i could not find anything in the documentation or in the code. I am using the default setup for the paginator:

```
f.defaults = {
    fillWidth: !0,
    highlightSelectedDate: !0,
    highlightToday: !0,
    hint: "dddd, Do MMMM YYYY",
    injectStyle: !0,
    itemWidth: 35,
    navItemWidth: 20,
    offDays: "Sat,Sun",
    offDaysFormat: "ddd",
    onSelectedDateChanged: null,
    selectedDate: moment().clone().startOf("day"),
    selectedDateFormat: "YYYY-MM-DD",
    selectedItemWidth: 140,
    showCalendar: !0,
    showOffDays: !0,
    showStartOfWeek: !0,
    size: d,
    startOfWeek: "Mon",
    startOfWeekFormat: "ddd",
    squareEdges: !1,
    text: "ddd<br/>Do",
    textSelected: "dddd<br/>Do, MMMM YYYY",
    useBootstrap2: !1,
    width: 0
}
```

Comment: As it depends upon moment.js, you may want to try fiddling with [moment locale](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/) and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was: `moment.locale('da', {..}` - http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/

Answer (score 0):

as example you can insert

```
this string - 
moment.locale("YOUR LOCALE");
```

before

```
f.defaults = {
fillWidth: !0
....
```

it will work

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve the same problem but the language needed to be changed dynamically. [Arthur Enokyan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37424856/855738) was a good starting point, but the language remained the one set initially.

What made it work for me was changing it inside the `_buildDate` method:

```
for (var m = start; m.isBefore(end); m.add('days', 1)) {
                // MY CODE BELOW 
                if (this.options.language) {
                    if (typeof m.lang === 'function') {
                        m.lang(this.options.language);
                    } else if (typeof m.locale === 'function') {
                        m.locale(this.options.language);
                    }
                }
```

The plugin used originally an older version of Moment, where you had to change the language with `moment.lang` so the code above supports both cases.

Just specify the language in the initialisation code's options like this:

```
var options = {
        language: 'en',
        selectedDateFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
    }
$('#paginator').datepaginator(options);
```

You can test the changes [here](http://awesomestsite.com/itsybitsybytes-blog-posts/bootstrap-date-paginator/), there are three different languages that you can choose from. Disclaimer, I made that demo page for a blog post where I explained in detail how I solved this exact problem with Bootstrap Date Paginator.